# Applying editnote script to one column and not entire sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, eventtrigger

I have a script in Google Sheets that auto-adds a note to cells that are edited/updated. The note shows a running log of edits made in the cell, thereby making the notes log. Example image of it in action:
[script in action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKVj4.png)

**ISSUE 1:**
I need this to happen only for one specific column in a specific sheet. However, it is doing this for every cell on every sheet in the workbook. I'm unsure how to do this.

**ISSUE 2:**
I want the date header for each entry to be bolded and cannot figure out how to do that as well.

**HOW I SET IT UP:**
I applied the following script:

```
function onEditNote() {
  
  // get spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('✏️Input');
  
  // get column range
  var activeCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  
  // get any existing cell value
  var currentCellValue = activeCell.getValue();
  Logger.log('Current cell value is: ' + currentCellValue);
  
  // get any existing cell Note
  var currentCellNote = activeCell.getNote();
  Logger.log('Current Note contains: ' + currentCellNote);
  
// This formats the date as US Central Time in the format
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date, "CST", "M.d.yy @ h:mm aaa:");
  Logger.log(formattedDate);
  
  // set Note on the edited cell with above information
  activeCell.setNote('' + formattedDate + '\n' + currentCellValue + '\n\n' + currentCellNote);
  
}
```

I then applied the follow Trigger settings on the script:
[Trigger settings on script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1alY.png)

How do I resolve my above issues using the script and settings that I established??

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Questions on this site should be specific, this mean that questions usually only include one "issue", also the question should included a brief description of what was tried to solve the specific issue being asked. Ref. [ask].

Answer (score 0):

#### Try this

```
function onEditNote(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == '✏️Input' && e.range.columnStart == 8) {
    var currentCellNote = e.range.getNote();
    var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date, "CST", "M.d.yy @ h:mm aaa:");
    e.range.setNote('' + formattedDate + '\n' + e.value + '\n\n' + currentCellNote);
  }
}
```

Comment:      :

function onEditNote(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == '✏️Input' && e.range.columnStart == "8") {
    var activeCell = sh.getActiveCell();
    var currentCellNote = e, range.getNote();
    var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date, "CST", "M.d.yy @ h:mm aaa:");
    e.range.setNote('' + formattedDate + '\n' + e.value + '\n\n' + currentCellNote);
  }
}

Comment:       :
“Syntax error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.' line: 5 file: Note Auto-Log.gs”

Comment:       ?

Comment: I tested it and it seems to be working now.

Comment: ,    ! ,         .  ?     
TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined
onEditNote @ Note Auto-Log.gs:2

Comment: You cannot run this function from the script editor or a menu because it requires the event object that populates e in the function declaration which it derives from the onedit trigger

Comment: Thanks again, Coopier. Unfortunately, I am new at scripting and do not know what any of that means. Are you saying that my asks are impossible within Google Sheets?

Comment: No I'm just saying that you setup the function  to run on a certain sheet and a certain column and then you go to that sheet and you edit that column and when you do the onEdit trigger will fire and your function will run.  I used Logger.log() and e.source.toast() to help me to figure out why it's not working when it doesn't.  The trigger prefills the first parameter of the onEdit() handlerfunction.